# If a database is totally encrypted how can a query work?

Tags: sql-server, database, encryption

We use SQL Server, soon to be upgraded to the latest version of SQL Server, which I believe is SQL Server 2017.  I'd like to be able to move some of our databases to the cloud, at least for development.  Our company has instituted a lot of security protocols, and some (important) people in the company are uncomfortable with PII information or corporate information being on the cloud.  Not that I blame them.  I've read that SQL Server databases can be encrypted, and have read some of the documentation.  This may be the solution to me being able to put some of our data in the cloud.

I can't get my head around how one could write a query against an encrypted database, without that database being at least temporarily decrypted.  Would the fields referenced in queries or views be converted to encrypted values for the query to run?  Or, is there some other way this is handled. I saw some stats on the overhead of TDS, and while it's not pretty, it may be doable.  Could anyone explain in not quite layman's terms how this encryption is handled?

Answer (score 0):

When you are doing a search against encrypted data, you would have to encrypt your search query in with the same algorithm the data was encrypted against. This eliminates the possibility for LIKE searches and for you to be able to show the data back in plain text however.

Answer (score 0):

> I can't get my head around how one could write a query against an encrypted database

There is difference if you encrypt the database or data.

Often the database itself can encrypt the database (such as MSSQL), or the hosting infrastructure can encrypt the data storage. In that case - the data themselves are stored encrypted, but the encryption is transparent to the authenticated clients (authenticated client will query the data as before, nothing changes). The key is managed by the infrastructure or database.

Another option is storing the data already encrypted by the client, e.g. encrypting only PII by the client  app.

Storing all data already encrypted would make either data not searchable or you will need to use deterministic (semantically non-secure) encryption. This is what previous answer suggested. For this there's even a nice tool [CryptDB](https://css.csail.mit.edu/cryptdb/) which act as an encryption proxxy over database queries.